# Load angularJs controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I had already declared my app and controller in separate file and below is how i am loading my controller html DOM but it is not showing that message. Can someone please guide how to achieve this.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="bnProblemList">
    <div ng-controller="problemListCtrl" data-ng-init="init()">
        <div ng-view="">this is my message = {{message}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
html = $j('#bnProblemList').html();
$compile(html)(scope);
```

Please let me know how to inject or load ng-controller html dynamically.

Comment: Is your `ng-app` set before use the `ng-controller` ? Is your controller include on your index ?

Comment: yes i had set ng-app as html attribute only..

Comment: and i am adding controller dynamically

Comment: It would be great if you can create a [Plunkr](http://http://plnkr.co/) for your app.

Answer (score 1):

Your controller declaration is wrong. You should do it like this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('problemListCtrl', ['$scope', 
  function($scope) {
      $scope.message = "This is my message :-)";
  }
]);
```

Comment: I had added this code in my main app.js which looks like below:-

Comment: var _versionNumber = "1.0", $stateProviderRef;
var moduleListToLoad = ['ui.router', 'oc.lazyLoad', 'ngRoute'];
var enkiApp = angular.module("enkiApp", moduleListToLoad);
enkiApp.controller('problemListCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', '$compile', function homeController($scope, $state, $compile) {        
    $scope.message = 'HOME PAGE';   
 $scope.init = function () {
  console.log("init");
 }; 
 $scope.$apply(function(){
   console.log("apply");
 });
    $state.go('ProblemList');
}]);
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, ['enkiApp']);
});

Answer (score 0):

A proper way is to declare your **Controller** into an anonymous function, and add it to a **module**. Then, you have to set your `ngApp`.

**Controller.js**

Here, we will declare our controller, and create an **app** module. Then, we will declare `ctrl` as our controller into our `app` module.

```
  (function(){

  function Controller($scope) {

    $scope.name = 'toto';

  }

  angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', Controller);

  })();
```

**HTML**

```
  <body ng-app='app' ng-controller="ctrl">

    <p>My name is {{name}}</p>

 </body>
```

And don't forget to include your **script tag** :

```
<script src="controller.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try Like below Example:-

Html Page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyApp">
<head>
 <title> Controller</title>  
 <script src="../Js/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script src="../Js/Controller.js"></script>   
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-controller="MyFirstController">
    {{ Msg }}
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

ControllerJs Page:

```
var MyApp=angular.module("MyApp",[]);
MyApp.controller("MyFirstController",function($scope){
  $scope.Msg="Hello First Conroller";
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
i was able to load/ inject controller dynamically by the help of below code

<div id="bn" ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">
    <div ui-view=''></div>
</div>

<script>
    angular.element(document).injector().invoke(function($compile, $state) {
        $state.go('myCtrl');
        var scope = angular.element($j("#bn")).scope();
        $compile($j("#bn"))(scope);
    });
</script>
```